# Lazy loading image to table view sections repeating

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for lazy loading images to my `tableView`.

With the following core i'm setting up my cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self getDataFromArrayOfDict:theDataObject.arrayOfTextData][indexPath.row]];

    if (indexPath.section == 1)
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self getDataFromArrayOfDict:theDataObject.arrayOfOtherData][indexPath.row]];

    if (indexPath.section == 2)
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self getDataFromArrayOfDict:theDataObject.arrayOfPictureData][indexPath.row]]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"]];
```

But the result is next:

On initial load:

[image]

After scrolling:

[image]

As you can see it somehow mixing data that i'm setting (i have only text in fist section, and only images in third), any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cells are dequeued and repeated in section 0 as per the screenshot.

you need to set the `cell.imageView.image = nil;` per cellForRowAtIndexPath call so that reused cell image clears up before you assign new image.